# Can I print a list without the brackets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

```
from itertools import product
A=((1,2),(3,4))
B= list(product(*A)) 
print (B)
```

my output is

```
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

but I want my output

```
(1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4)
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: I've given your question a meaningful title, please in future provide one when you are posting.

Comment: And the answer is `print(*B)` rather than `print(B)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters hello thanx for your concern

Answer (score 1):

simply use:

```
print (*B)
```

outputs:

```
(1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4)
```